# Querying for an Unknown Interface Type

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

In this code:

```
TTest<IntfT: IInterface> = class
protected
  fObj : TInterfacedObject;
public
  function  GetVal: IntfT;
end;
```

How would I implement the GetVal function if I want it to return fObj as an IntfT?

I've tried:

```
result := fObj as IntfT;
```

and

```
fObj.QueryInterface(IntfT,result);
```

and

```
result := fObj as IInterface;
```

but nothing seems to work. This seems like such a simple thing, I keep thinking I must be missing something.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

What looks the most promising to me right now is QueryInterface. Currently the compiler complains that IntfT isn't a GUID and I get the impression that if I had the appropriate GUID everything would be happy. Anyone know of a way to get the IID from an interface type that would work in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
function TTest<IntfT>.GetVal: IntfT;
begin
  fObj.QueryInterface(GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T)).Guid,result);
end;
```

And that seems to work. (BTW, it works because fObj isn't really a TInterfacedObject, but a different interface implementing class that has a public QueryInterface method).

Comment: Nice! But even with TInterfacedObject, you could use this:

(FObj as IInterface).QueryInterface(GetTypeData(TypeInfo(IntfT)).Guid, Result);

Answer (score 2):

`result := fObj as IntfT;` ought to work, but apparently the compiler doesn't quite understand interfaces as generics.  You should report this in QC.

`fObj.QueryInterface(IntfT,result);` doesn't work because QueryInterface is a **protected** member of TInterfacedObject.  Also, QueryInterface works by calling GetInterface, which looks for a GUID, and GUIDs and generics don't mix all that well.

`result := fObj as IInterface;` does compile right for me.  What problem are you having with it?

Comment: Well, son of a.... yes, it does work. In my actual code I was typecasting from an Items[] property, which should have been of an interface supporting type, but for some reason, with the generics, it didn't recognize that. Bug if I explicitly typecast my Items object to the interface supporting type, suddenly it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm... at a closer look, "result := fObj as IInterface" doesn't seem to work so well after all. It just delays the compiler error until later. When you actually attempt to use GetVal as the appropriate type, I get a compiler error saying "Incompatible types: 'ISomething' and 'IInterface'"